# Parse XML only returns first element

Tags: xml, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am new to robot framework's XML library.
I tried parsing an xml to get a value in it, but it would only get the very first element.
So my XML is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Header>
    <firstElement>
        <secondElement>
            <myValue>...</myValue>
            <mySecondValue>...</mySecondValue>
            ...
        </secondElement
    </firstElement>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
  ...
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My very short robot framework test looks like this:

```
 ${xml}=    Parse Xml    path/to/xml
 ${first}=    get element    ${xml}    myValue
 Log  ${first}
```

But when parsing the XML, it logs it like this:

```
INFO : ${xml} = <Element 'Envelope' at 0x00000000042B67C8>
```

Of course all my attempts to get values in the parsed xml failed, I get:

```
FAIL : No element matching 'myValue' found.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the xpath you're using to find the element, have a look here: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Finding%20elements%20with%20xpath

It should look like this:

```
    ${x}=    Parse Xml    ${xml}    
    ${el_my_value}=    Get Element    ${x}    .//myValue
    Log  ${el_my_value}
    ${first_text}=    Get Element Text    ${el_my_value}
```

Notice that `.//myValue`.

Also, if you want to get element **text**, then you need to use keyword [`Get Element Text`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Element%20Text).

So the whole working example and result:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    XML
Variables    ../../Resources/xml_test.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test XML Parsing
    ${x}=    Parse Xml    ${xml}    
    ${el_my_value}=    Get Element    ${x}    .//myValue
    Log  ${el_my_value}
    ${first_text}=    Get Element Text    ${el_my_value}
```

[image]