# Tosa puzzle with RobotFrameWork: read string text from a certain point till a certain point

Tags: robotframework

The source is this obstacle: https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/87912

What I got this far is:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library    Browser
Library    XML
Library    Collections
Library    String

Documentation     BE FAST AUTOMATE
*** Variables ***
${links}=  <isbn>
${rechts}=  </isbn>

*** Test Cases ***
Execute a for loop only three times
    Open Browser    https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/87912
    Click    id=loadbooks
    ${alles}=  Get Text    id=books
```

This one is mentioned: 'hard'

The Get Text literally gets all the text which is fine, but from that point I have no clue how the get the isbn (from the specific, or even ... any)

Comment: linking to external site without even giving a short description of the problem here ?

Comment: read the xml (using a xml library), find the key with the value of the book and then get the id. easy

Comment: @ClaudioBatista I did actually read the XML library documentation. I found it a bit hard actually. And if I wasn't asking I would know how to do it. So for the people whom are far less expierenced then you. Can you show us how that would look like. please.

Comment: @ClaudioBatista to be honest the documentation ( https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html ) of the XML library is not that clear, to my opinion it is in contrast to some other librarys hard to read. sort of fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

A bit further thanks to this page: [Parse XML only returns first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146320/parse-xml-only-returns-first-element)

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser  enable_presenter_mode=False
Library    XML
Library    Collections
Library    String

Documentation     BE FAST AUTOMATE
*** Variables ***
#@{ROBOTS}=        1    2    3
${links}=  <isbn>
${rechts}=  </isbn>

*** Test Cases ***
Find the isbn
    Open Browser    https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/87912
    sleep  5s
    Click    id=loadbooks
    ${alles}=  Get Text    id=books
    ${x}=    Parse Xml    ${alles}    
    ${el_my_value}=    XML.Get Element    ${x}    .//isbn
    Log  ${el_my_value}
    ${first_text}=    Get Element Text    ${el_my_value}
```

but now I still need the isbn corresponding to the correct title.

because the response is: Multiple elements (6) matching './/isbn' found.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I should post this as you are suppose to build the answer to the exercise, not google it...
Nevertheless, here it goes.

The data is hidden and if you carefully look into the html of the page you will see that after clicking the button "Load books" a javascript function is kicked that will set the value into the xml and into a variable.
After knowing this information is very simple to get the value that we want just using simple robot + selenium:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Insert Correct ISBN
   Open Browser    https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/87912   Chrome
   Click Element    id=loadbooks
   ${isbnValue}    Execute Javascript    return isbn
   Input Text    id=isbn    ${isbnValue}
```

Comment: that is somewhat helpful. 2 things: 1) The 'Browser' library is the one I'd like to use. 2) that doesn't lead to the specific variant (belonging to the title)

Comment: one more thing, the actual build purpose is with Tosca, what I do is something I made up myself. (Just for excercise purposes)